# Binary tree recursion java

Tags: java, string, recursion, binary-tree

I want to write a function which returns a string of 0s and 1s to signify a path from root Node to specific node p, where 0 means go left, and 1 means go right.

```
    __3__
   /     \
  4       5 
 / \     / 
9   2    1
```

2 should return "01"

```
public String traverse(TreeNode root, TreeNode p,String s) {
    if (root == p) return s;
    if (root.left != null) return traverse(root.left,p,s + "0");

    if (root.right != null) return traverse(root.right,p,s+ "1"); 

    return "-1";
  }
```

This is my idea of recursive way but it just returns -1 when it gets to a leaf, whereas i want it to continue the recursion. As in, to find 2, it tries 3 -> 4-> 9, but does not continue 4's recursion, but stops at 9. What can I do?

Comment: Did you step through your code in your IDE debugger? What did you find?

Comment: Basically that it stops at the leftmost leaf, which in the example is 9. I want it to recognize that the leaf, 9, is not the node im looking for, 2, and continue on the recursion on the right for 4, but i need a return statement at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a special *sentinel* value, "-1" when you don't find the value you're looking for on a particular branch of the tree.

But you're not checking for this value anywhere in your code - when the value you're looking for isn't on the left branch of the tree, you need to search in the right branch.

So, you need to add a check after searching the left branch of the tree that you didn't get the sentinel value as the result. If you did, you need to continue searching.

```
public String traverse(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, String s) {
    if (root == p) {
        return s;
    }
    if (root.left != null) {
        String result = traverse(root.left, p, s + "0");
        if (!"-1".equals(result)) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    if (root.right != null) {
        return traverse(root.right, p, s + "1");
    }
    return "-1";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this is a great solution